# yii2: How to integrate AdminBSB Theme

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I'm using `yii2` advanced framework.  And I am using `AdminBSB` theme for my layout. But this error appears. I tried on searching for same issues. But I can't figure it out. Here is the error when I inspect:

> Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).yiiActiveForm is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument.

Some say I declare `JS` twice. But I didn't declare it twice or I didn't notice It call twice because of my template.

Below is how I am loading the javascript in my Asset Manager file.

```
public $js = [
    "plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js",
    "plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js",
    "plugins/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.js",
    "plugins/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.js",
    "plugins/node-waves/waves.js",
    "plugins/flot-charts/jquery.flot.js",
    "plugins/jquery-sparkline/jquery.sparkline.js",
    "js/admin.js"
];
```

Comment: It would help if you posted some of your code around where you call `jQuery(...).yiiActiveForm`

Comment: I updated my question. thank you

Comment: Add the piece of code where you call the function, no your asset declaration

Comment: all i did was I use activeform on my form: `<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>` then that error display

Comment: Can you please try commenting the following line from AppAsset "plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js", and even changing the id of that particular form

Comment: what line? everything that I use in asset was needed for my theme

Comment: I tried it. but some buttons in my theme didn't function well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had the same theme and i also faced this error and that is because the `yiiActiveForm` is loaded before the `jquery` file does, even if you will fix that it will get in conflict with `bootstrap` js file that functions for the dropdown in the dashboard under user image. I advise you to change the loading of `jquery` and `bootstrap` to the following, you need to make some changes to you `AppAsset.php` file.

1.Remove the `bootstrap` and `jquery` links from the `$js` and `$css` arrays in the `AppAsset.php`.

2.Update your `$depends` array to the following.

```
 public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset',
    ];
```

3.Then update your **`frontend/config/main.php`** to the following.

```
'assetManager' => [
            'bundles' => [
                'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
                    'sourcePath' => null, 'js' => ['//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js'],
                ],
                'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
                    'sourcePath' => null, 'css' => ['//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css'],
                ],
                'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset' => [
                    'sourcePath' => null, 'js' => ['//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Comment: risky? for what @top

Comment: co'z i'm not familiar how to do it :(, it's my fault i didn't fix it from the start. and now i'm almost done my project. I'm thinking what if it co'z more bugs when I do your solution hehe

Comment: haha, i faced the similar issue in my project too, you got to try it once you can do it in a separate branch if you have git so that you can discard it if it doesnot work, bu i think it should

Comment: yeah I'll try it. thanks dude. I'll update you incase it didn't work to me hehe

Comment: sure will sort it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164144/discussion-between-top-and-muhammad-omer-aslam).

Comment: bro i want to try it now. can we discuss it on chat? i badly need your help hehe. thank in advance

Comment: sure thing why not just go ahead an update the changes you need and paste any problems you run into